# Not being redirected to the next page required Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

After entering the fields of `EventForm` I am not being redirected to `display:eventexe` ,which is the `EventDetailView`. Instead I am being redirected to the same page where I entered the Form Details.

**views.py**

```
class FileEventView(FormView):
    template_name = 'display/events.html'
    form_class = EventForm    

    def form_valid(self, form):        
        event_up = EventModel()
        event_up.save()      
        self.id = event_up.id
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('display:eventexe', kwargs={'pk': self.id})    

class EventDetailView(DetailView):
    model = FileModel
    template_name = 'display/eventexe.html'
```

Comment: After you POST the form, is the `EventModel` instance saved into the database? Maybe the posted form is invalid and it is calling the `form_invalid` function instead of `form_valid` and your template isn't displaying all the error messages correctly

Comment: What @Vitor Freitas said... I hate when that happens. Try printing the raw form at the top of your template to see what crops up with `{{ form }}`

Comment: @dotcomly , Vitor was right ..I got my error.  form_invalid function got executed . I messed up with urls part. It was a very silly mistake on my part.